# How do I run functions with different CommandFlags value?

Tags: vb.net, autocad, autocad-plugin

I have two DLL files. Let's call them:

1. DoSomething01.dll
2. DoSomething02.dll

The use case I'm working on both of these DLLs is described by the following steps:

1. Open Drawing01.dwg and Drawing02.dwg in AutoCAD.
2. Load DoSomething01.dll into AutoCAD by NETLOAD in the command line.
3. Load DoSomething02.dll into AutoCAD by NETLOAD in the command line.
4. I run a function from DoSomething01.dll from the command line of Drawing01.dwg.
5. I run a function from DoSomething02.dll from the command line of Drawing02.dwg.
6. Click something on the drawing (as an input for the function on DoSomething02.dll).

What I am trying to do is run the functions of the two DLLs from one operation -- essentially performing steps no. 4 to 6 in one function call in a new DLL file.

The code in my new DLL file goes like this:

```
Dim acDocDwg01 As Document
Dim acDocDwg02 As Document

<CommandMethod("DOITALL", CommandFlags.Session)>
Public Sub AllInOneFunction()
    Dim dosomething01 As New DoSomething01.clsMain
    Dim dosomething02 As New DoSomething02.clsMain

    Dim acDocMgr As DocumentCollection = Application.DocumentManager

    If isBothDrawingsOpened() Then
        ' Activate Drawing01 document
        acDocMgr.MdiActiveDocument = acDocDwg01
        dosomething01.createStuff()

        ' Activate Drawing02 document
        acDocMgr.MdiActiveDocument = acDocDwg02
        dosomething02.createMoreStuff()
    End If
End Sub

Private Function isBothDrawingsOpened() As Boolean
    Dim flag As Boolean

    'Collection of all opened documents
    Dim acadDocs As DocumentCollection = Application.DocumentManager
    Dim acDoc As Document
    Dim acCurDb As Database

    Dim d1, d2 As Boolean

    For Each acDoc In acadDocs
        acCurDb = acDoc.Database
        If acCurDb.Filename = "Drawing01" > 0 Then
            d1 = True
            acDocDwg01 = acDoc
        ElseIf acCurDb.Filename = "Drawing02" > 0 Then
            d2 = True
            acDocDwg02 = acDoc
        End If
        modLog.LogWrite(1, "Current Document: " & acDoc.Name)
    Next acDoc

    If (d1 And d2) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please open both Drawing01.dwg and Drawing02.dwg before executing this function.")
        flag = False
    Else
        flag = True
    End If

    Return flag

End Function
```

**The problem is...** since I need to switch between two Documents (Drawing), I need to use `CommandFlags.Session`. But the function in step no. 6, uses `CommandFlags.UsePickSet`. The code I provided just runs through the code on the function of DoSomething02.dll without waiting for user input (click).

I have read from [AutoDesk documentation](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-NET/files/GUID-F77E8FE0-8034-4704-93BD-F717608F8223-htm.html) that:

> You can specify the use of more than one flag by using the + operator in VB.NET and the | operator in C#.

```
<CommandMethod("CheckForPickfirstSelection", CommandFlags.UsePickSet + _
                                             CommandFlags.NoBlockEditor)> _
Public Sub CheckForPickfirstSelection()
 . . .
End Sub
```

I tried doing that but it doesn't work. The behavior is the same.

UPDATE:
I tried reversing the sequence of operations:

```
    If isBothDrawingsOpened() Then
        ' Activate Drawing02 document
        acDocMgr.MdiActiveDocument = acDocDwg02
        dosomething02.createMoreStuff()

        ' Activate Drawing01 document
        acDocMgr.MdiActiveDocument = acDocDwg01
        dosomething01.createStuff()
    End If
```

It actually waits for me click on the Drawing before proceeding. The issue might be related to Document activation (switching). I can actually see the active documents change as the code runs, but after it switches, user can no longer interrupt interactively (?). Or maybe am I missing something in how to activate or switch into the Document?

Comment: May need to use the 'Or' operator instead of plus sign, if the argument is treated as bit flag enumerated values.

Comment: Yes, I also tried using Or since using + requires me to remove Options Strict On. The resulting behavior is the same.

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps you could force the focus on the drawing after setting acDocDwg01 current.  Like: Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.MainWindow.Focus();

Comment: Ahh, I forgot I left a question here in SO. Yeah, I did precisely just that. Kindly make a separate answer so I can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but perhaps you could force the focus on the drawing after setting acDocDwg01 current.
 Like: Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.MainWindow.Focus();